# Count consecutive row values but reset count with every 0 in row

Tags: python, finance, counting, cumulative-sum, quantitative-finance

Within a dataframe, I need to count and sum consecutive row values in `column A` into a new column, `column B`.

Starting with `column A`, the script would count the consecutive runs in `1s` but when a `0` appears it prints the total count in `column B`, it then resets the count and continues through the remaining data.

#### Desired outcome:

```
A | B
0   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
0   4
0   0
1   0
1   0
0   2
```

I've tried using `.shift()` along with various `if-statements` but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: If you have made an attempt, please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a way to do it. Probably there exists a more elegant solution.

```
df['B'] = df['A'].groupby(df['A'].ne(df['A'].shift()).cumsum()).cumsum().shift(fill_value=0) * (df['A'].diff() == -1)
```

This part `df['A'].groupby(df['A'].ne(df['A'].shift())` groups the data by consecutive occurences of values.
Then we take the cumsum which counts the cumulated sum along each group. Then we shift the results by 1 row because you want the count after the group. Then we mask out all the rows which are not the last row of the group + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. However, I get the feeling that there might be better ways.. But you can try this for now:

- The routine function is use to increment the counter variable until it encounters a value of `0` in the `A` column. At which point it grabs the total count, and then resets the counter variable.
- I use a `for-loop` to iterate through the `A` column, and append the returned `B` values to a list
- This list is then inserted into the dataframe.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]})

def routine(row, c):
    val = 0
    if row:
        c += 1
    else:
        val = c
        c = 0
    return(val, c)

B_vals = []
counter = 0
for item in df['A'].values:
    b, counter = routine(item, counter)
    B_vals.append(b)

df['B'] = B_vals
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  1  0
3  1  0
4  1  0
5  0  4
6  0  0
7  1  0
8  1  0
9  0  2
```